# What is the best way to reference a login file in an autorun SQL query via Task Scheduler? Multiple Database schemas and a yearly password reset

Tags: sql, passwords, scheduled-tasks, login-script, advanced-query-tool

I'm admittedly fairly new at SQL and learning organically through project requests and reviewing my predecessor's previous processes. One issue I am encountering is the once-per-year password reset rules my company has in place. All current queries have a Database schema being referenced (6 potential options depending on the query, most referencing the same user and password), and hard-coded user login information. So once per year, every single query has to be changed to the updated encrypted password.

I have been testing a login sql file that AQT references prior to running the query, allowing it to login to the necessary database for the data. The goal is to only have to change the password in 5 or 6 places instead of 300 since I was unsuccessful in being omitted from the reset rules. We use AQT v10 if that helps. All of our queries are run via Windows Task Scheduler on a virtual Windows 10 machine.

I am able to get the login sql file to work properly, and the query to run and export the data to the correct csv. The issue I am encountering is the task realizing the end of the query and closing AQT all together. Most of our processes are individual queries run in order to compile the data required for whatever the task is at hand. So with AQT remaining open, the machine does not know to begin the next step of the task.

Below is the link that helped point toward the login sql file and 'include' in the initial scripting of the query
https://www.querytool.com/help/329.htm

[Autorun with AQT remaining open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lbYa.png)

[Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5g5d.png)

[SQL Login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeSr0.png)

Thanks!
Andy

Comment: What database server are you targeting? Some (including SQL Server) support [Windows authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/authentication-in-sql-server) which avoids issues like this.

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response. It was actually the default settings on my computer that were keeping AQT open. The method above worked perfectly, may not have been the best approach but it worked so I'm happy!